# How to make html hover over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to fix my code for ages no matter how much I hover over the hamburger menu image the cursor just would not change:

I've already added pointer cursor in the `div` but it still would not work. I already added the `.menu:hover` but it still would not work. I do not know what is wrong with my code if there is someone out there that could help me than please do thank you.

```js
const menuTog = document.querySelector(".menu");
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav");
const navLeft = document.querySelector(".nav-left");
const navRight = document.querySelector(".nav-right");
const navLinks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links"));
const contact = document.querySelector('.contact');
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');

menuTog.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuTog.classList.toggle('active');
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  navLeft.classList.toggle('active');
  navRight.classList.toggle('active');
  logo.classList.toggle('active');

  contact.classList.remove('active');
  navRight.classList.remove('active');

  if (menuTog.classList.contains('active')) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navRight.classList.add('active');
    }, 100)
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 110px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  right: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  transition: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <h1 class="nav1">CEA</h1>
    <h1 class="line"></h1>

  </nav>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="nav-left ">
      <!--active-->

      <ul>
        <li class="nav-link"> <a class="large" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"> <a class="large" href="#">Our Work</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"> <a class="large" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"> <a class="small" href="#">Web Design</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"> <a class="small" href="#">eCommerce</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"> <a class="small" href="#">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="contact">
        <p class="large">Get in touch</p>
        <p class="small">0302101290391</p>
        <p class="small">dsagasdasgas@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right ">
      <!--active-->

    </div>
    <img src="Images\menu.png" alt="menu" class="menu" style="z-index: 10;">
  </nav>


</div>
```

Comment: hovering over the .menu img changes the cursor just fine

Comment: Please, improve your English. "Ive", "idk", "theres", "wouldnt", etc., are a lack of respect for the community. You can edit your question.

Comment: This is an excellent learning experience! It's worth the trouble of figuring it out. However, if you are on a deadline, I would suggest using a JS library for this.

Comment: Most probably you have another, transparent element hover on top of the menu and cover it.
Try to right click+inspect the image and check on which element do you land